# Instant Way To Set Objects' Distance In Circular Pattern

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow

Is there any automatic way to convert this pattern

[image]

To this one?

[image]

I have trying to use `Scale` with `Manipulate center points` enabled, but it does nothing.

Comment: Are you searching for this result https://imgur.com/gallery/FI5Vc9w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the vanes are separate objects, and you're in Object Mode..

The scaling of the center points isn't working because they are all already at 0.

Select all of the objects, and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > 'Origin to Geometry'.

The scaling of the center points should now have an effect.
If you need the slight spiraling effect in the second picture, then. still manipulating center points only, rotate the objects in their common plane, about their common center.

Comment: I dunno if thats what he wants cause when U look on the 2nd picture all these parts are not "mirroring" the opposite ones ... they are slightly moved (if this has to be the desired effect). Could U please specify KeepMove?

Comment: @JanMatys . good point.. I've edited in case that's what he wants.

Comment: Yep, now its a correct answer imo. U R quite welcome Robin ;)

Comment: I was going to do that, but my time was over.